# How can I compress an mp3 file?

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, compression, lame

I used to download a program in windows that used lame to compress audio of mp3 files and made them smaller in size but I don't know how to do this in Ubuntu.

Does anybody know anything about this?

Please remember that I have just installed ubuntu so I practically don't know anything.

Comment: They have to have the same name as it seems. Is this what are you looking for: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/lame.1.html ? (Look at the description)

Answer (score 28):

#### Terminal way:

`lame` is in Universe repository. So you have to first enable universe repository.

- See this question → [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/61218)
- Then install lame by the below using commands in a terminal. To open a terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install lame
  ```

Then navigate to the directory by using `cd` command to the folder you have the file to convert it. I assume your file is in Desktop directory and it's name is `001.mp3`. We also assume your input file is of 128kbps and you want an output file of 32kbps. So, use these commands to compress it

```
cd ~/Desktop
lame -b 32  001.mp3 001-32.mp3
```

<sup>You can use any name for the output file other than the same name as input file which is in this case 001.mp3.</sup>

Note that, the conversion will use fixed bitrate as opposed to variable or average bitrate.

See the [lame manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lame.1.html) for more help.

#### Graphical way:

If you prefer graphical tools to do this, I suggest you a small and simple tool to do so. It is soundconverter.

1. Install it with this link → [soundconverter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/soundconverter) [image: Install soundconverter] or using this command in terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get install soundconverter
   ```
2. Open it by searching in Dash with term "soundconverter". To bring Dash, Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key which is also known as Windows key.
3. When it opened, Press the **Add File* button in it's toolbar, and select the file you want to convert.
4. Then go to *Edit* → *Preference* from menu. In **Type of result** select **mp3** and select a quality.

   - Very low = 64 kbps
   - Low = 96 kbps
   - Normal = 128 kbps
   - High = 192 kbps
   - Very high = 256 kbps.

   I think, you should select "Very low" or "Low" depending on your needs. Then click close.
5. Click **Convert** button in toolbar to convert it.

That's it. Your file will be converted and stored in the same directory as the input file. You can also change the directory for output folder in Preference Window.

Comment: @Juancho I updated my answer. See whether it was causing problem.

Comment: Thank You Very Much...Working fine

Comment: I am using lame and it works; but I wonder whether it is posssible to really shrink the file size even more. For example, I have a cat meow .mp3 here - for 8 seconds it is 32kb in size. That seems so long for something that is basically simple ... there is a bit of noise in the audio sample too. I'd love to read tips how to reduce the file size even more. Text compresses so much nicer IMO and you can find so much more guides on the www for this too...

Answer (score 4):

If you need a tool with a graphical user interface, then you can use [Soundconverter](http://soundconverter.org/). You can open the **software-center** and search for it or you install it manually via terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

[Download / Install for Ubuntu](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/soundconverter)

[image: Soundconverter]

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
lame -b [bitrate] input.mp3 output.mp3
```