# reduce mp3 size from terminal ?

Tags: command-line, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I compress an mp3 file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184747/how-can-i-compress-an-mp3-file)

Hi is there any way to reduce the size of MP3 file from terminal ? I am Using Ubuntu 12.04 .I would like to have it only terminal methods not in GUI ways .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Maybe this question/answer could help you:
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/184747/how-can-i-compress-an-mp3-file][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/184747/how-can-i-compress-an-mp3-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a search and found cutmp3 might be what your looking for.  It is command line and looks like it can edit mp3's.

Comment: how can i use it,  to compress size ?

Comment: @August From you post you wanted to reduce the size.  There are other programs for compression.  This can cut out silence and other things which will reduce the size. Here are some links which might help[link](http://www.puchalla-online.de/cutmp3.html) also this link might help [link] (http://linux.die.net/man/1/cutmp3)

Answer (score 4):

If it is about size in bytes, then you can decrease the bitrate, for example, this will shrink the size. For this you have several options, what I use is `avconv` (in the past `ffmpeg`). See the manuals with `man avconv` or `man ffmpeg`.